# What is the effect of the oxidation number of iron on the properties of ferroin complex?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

In our labratory expermient, we have determined the isobestic point for iron(III) complexation with ortho-phenanthroline, and we have also studied iron(II) complexation with ortho-phenanthroline by spectrophotometry. What does the isobestic point tell us and how can we answer the asked question?

Comment: It is [Isosbestic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosbestic_point)

Comment: Answers on CH SE site are figuratively paid by the user's own effort. When you ask, you are supposed to search and thoroughly think about the topic and to provide explicit compact summary of partial answers or at least ideas you have got until then. Effort not shown may be  considered as effort not done.